# getting pyqt to use cocoa widgets

Tags: python, cocoa, qt4, pyqt

The widgets in my application are the old style mac widgets.  How do I make them become the new style ones.  I am using pyqt 4.6.3-1 with python 2.7 on os x 10.6.  Everything was installed using fink and I installed both qt4-mac and qt4-x11.  Not sure which is being used or how to select one or the other.

Comment: If Qt can't get bothered to use Cocoda widgets, you're pretty much out of luck if you want to stay with Qt.

Comment: @delnan: of course you can use Qt with new style widgets, but you would have to create your own QNewMacStyle or something alike based on the normal QMacStyle.... well Qt is open-source, so you can do this!

Comment: you need qt/pyqt built with cocoa for that, I think

Comment: @Eli, do you know how to build qt/pyqt for cocoa?  Also, I have been using your pyqt/matplotlib tutorials.  Thanks!

Comment: nope, but I imagine Qt at least should already have a version built with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched from Fink to Macports, and I got the nice widgets.